# rescaling X axis

Tags: plotting

I have a pretty simple code, working fine and producing a plot that is ALMOST what I desire:

```
b2[K_] := 1 - (K/938.27 + 1)^-2

Fbeta[K_] := Log[1.02*10^6*b2[K]/(1 - b2[K])] - b2[K]
dEdx[K_] := 0.17/b2[K]*(Fbeta[K] - 4.31)

myplot = Plot[NIntegrate[1/dEdx[K], {K, kappa, K0}] /
              NIntegrate[1/dEdx[K], {K, 0, K0}], {kappa, 0, 1000}]
```

Basically I would like the x-axis to be rescaled so that it goes from 0 to 1. I have made several tries substituting the variables, but only got a bunch of errors and I have run out of ideas ...

Is there a simple method I am not aware of to normalize the values on the x-axis?

Comment: What's a reasonable value for K0?

Answer (score 2):

You did not define `K0` so I added a `Manipulate` to control its value.

```
b2[K_] := 1 - (K/938.27 + 1)^-2

Fbeta[K_] := Log[1.02*10^6*b2[K]/(1 - b2[K])] - b2[K] 

dEdx[K_] := 0.17/b2[K]*(Fbeta[K] - 4.31)

Manipulate[
 myplot = Plot[
   NIntegrate[1/dEdx[K], {K, 1000 kappa, K0}]/
    NIntegrate[1/dEdx[K], {K, 0, K0}], {kappa, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}],
 {{K0, 1000, Subscript[K, 0]}, 1000, 5000, 25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: ... to control its value, +1.